# webMethods BPM process upgrade

Tags: process, version, upgrade, business-process-management, webmethods

Currently I get a headache thinking about a process upgrade (new version) of a webMethods-BPM-process.

I know that a process instance always runs in the process-version it was started with. I also know that after the deployment of a new version of a process all new process-instances are based on the new version.

As long as the interfaces of the process do not change between versions everything is fine. But enough about paradise...

In my world the **interfaces change** - always. That leads to the point where I have two possibilities:

1. Implement **compatibility code** with each update in each used/changed interface - this will lead to a very ugly codebase after multiple updates...
2. **Update the process-instances**.

I would like to try the second approach - but I have no idea how. Parse the process state and create a new one?

Can I solve my problem with webMethods?

Comment: Can you elaborate more, what you want to achieve? It would be the best with some examples. You have let say `foo(A a)`  and you want to change it to `bar(B b)` in a process?